# How to check when an exe application ends?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I am creating an application in C# which calls a batch file, then executes another .net exe file and then runs another batch file when the exe file is closed.

I can run the initial batch file and I can call the exe file using the `Process.start(my.exe);` method but how can I check when the exe file is finally terminated so that I can run the final batch file?

Comment: @George Stocker this question seems real to me..

Comment: @Blorgbeard the problem is that the question (both in its current state and in the state it was before your helpful edit) lacked a few things: Research on the part of the OP, as well as what code they've tried to use that hasn't worked.  We do expect a certain amount of minimum effort from the OP (to keep Stack Overflow from becoming a 'Do my work for me' place), and this question didn't surpass that bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either call [WaitForExit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx):

```
myProcess.WaitForExit():
```

> When an associated process exits (that is, when it is shut down by the
>   operation system through a normal or abnormal termination), the system
>   stores administrative information about the process and returns to the
>   component that had called WaitForExit(). The Process component can
>   then access the information, which includes the ExitTime, by using the
>   Handle to the exited process.

Or, [enable events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) and hook code on the [exited event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx):

```
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
```

...

```
private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exit time:    {0}\r\n" +
        "Exit code:    {1}\r\nElapsed time: {2}", myProcess.ExitTime, myProcess.ExitCode, elapsedTime);
}
```

The key difference is synchronous or asynchronous.  From the exited docs:

> There are two ways of being notified when the associated process
>   exits: synchronously and asynchronously. Synchronous notification
>   relies on calling the WaitForExit method to pause the processing of
>   your application until the associated component exits. Asynchronous
>   notification relies on the Exited event. In either case,
>   EnableRaisingEvents must be set to true for the Process component to
>   receive notification that the process has exited.

Also, when you get to running batch file, check out this post:

[How to execute a batch file from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026888/how-to-execute-a-batch-file-from-c)

Comment: Thank you. The WaitForExit() was not working for me but after enabling the events, it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You may use [Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) property to determine whether the process you starting in your application has terminated or not.

[Process.WaitForExit - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx)

> Instructs the Process component to wait indefinitely for the
>   associated process to exit.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Process object returned from Process.Start(string), you can call WaitForExit().

So:

```
Process process = Process.Start(programFileName); // Starts the program

// ... do some other stuff here, if necessary

process.WaitForExit(); // Waits indefinitely for the process to finish
process.Close(); // Frees resources associated with the process

// ... do other stuff here
```

Comment: This did not seem to work for me. However, when I enabled the events as Bryanmac said, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        //...config your process
        p.Exited += new EventHandler((s, e) =>
        {
            if (p.ExitCode == 0)
            {
                /*Launch your final batch*/
            }
            else
            {

            }

        });
        p.Start();
```

Comment: +1 - nice way to express the callback code inline ...

Answer (score 0):

when you start the exe with Process.start(), you have a `Process` object ... have a look at the `Exited` event and the `EnableRaisingEvents` Property of that object